# Convert textarea tab spaced data into 2D json format

Tags: javascript

I want to convert tab spaced data (pasted from excel file) into a valid 2 dimension json array. I have tried to make simple javascript for that. Please take a look. JSON output data format should be:

```
[{a:1, b:232},{a:2, b:432},{a:3, b:212},{a:4, b:543},{a:5, b:123},]
```

```js
var data = document.getElementById("values").split('  ').map(function(d){return +d});
console.log(data)
```

```html
<textarea id='test'>
1 232
2 432
3 212
4 543
5 123
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things to consider,

1. You used the wrong ID, should be: `document.getElementById("test")`
2. You did not split on new-lines
3. You did not map to an object

```js
const text = document.getElementById('test').value;
const data = text.trim().split('\n').map(line => {
  let tokens = line.trim().split(/\s+/).map(str => parseInt(str, 10));
  return { a: tokens[0], b: tokens[1] };
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<textarea id="test">
1 232
2 432
3 212
4 543
5 123
</textarea>
```

---

### Update

A more dynamic example:

```js
const main = () => {
  const csv = document.getElementById('test').value;

  console.log(csvToJson(csv, {
    fields: [ 'a', 'b' ],
    autoParseValues : true
  }));
};

const DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
  delimiter : '\t',
  autoParseValues : false
};

function csvToJson(csv, options) {
  let opts = Object.assign({}, DEFAULT_OPTIONS, options);
  let hasFields = opts.fields != null && opts.fields.length !== 0;
  return csv.trim().split('\n').map(line => {
    let values = line.trim().split(opts.delimiter).map(value => {
      if (opts.autoParseValues) {
        if (!isNaN(value)) {
          return parseInt(value, 10);
        }
      }
      return value;
    });
    return !hasFields ? values : opts.fields.reduce((res, field, idx) => {
      return Object.assign(res, { [field] : values[idx] });
    }, {});
  });
}

main();
```

```html
<textarea id="test">
1 232
2 432
3 212
4 543
5 123
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time and reply, I am wondering if I can add some preset values in the array like array name, color etc. One more thing it is also showing NaN and undefined values in the last so can we remove that

Comment: @Instanano I added a more dynamic example, with options. Check it out, hopefully it helps you understand better.